# Flash Displaying Weird Text in a Dynamic Text Field

Tags: flash, actionscript, textfield

I am working in Flash CS5 and I have placed a text field (dynamic, classic text) on the stage. I am accessing it through Actionscript on the same frame like this:

```
var ct:TextField = TextField(getChildByName("Temperature"));
ct.text = "Hello world";
```

What ACTUALLY appears is this:

```
eo wor
```

So... The H, Ls, and D are gone. Mysteriously. Without warning. I am sitting here utterly confused. Is this just me?

PS. The text field is set to Myriad Pro Bold, a font on my computer, so it isn't like it's a font problem.

Comment: check if the problem remains when no font/text format settings are defined

Comment: Whew, that worked. I took off the shadow, bold, and font and the problem went away. Oddly enough, when I readded each of the effects the problem went away. Bugs-- I hate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so re-adding style properties fixed it. you should feel lucky ;)

Answer (score 2):

Its a font embedding issue when this happens.
Click Embedding and select numerals and whatever else you need "All" possible.
Then you want to select the embedded font for other items too, it's something like "Arial*".

Comment: The problem is, it happened with Myriad Pro, _sans-serif, and other default fonts-- none of which I was embedding.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same bad result when I opened a Flash CS4 file in Flash CS5, saved it in CS5 and then ran it (with NO error messages, by the way).

Here is how I fixed it: I deleted the dynamic test field and recreated it and renamed it with the same instance name. Then it was fine. Maybe it is because of the new text capabilities in CS5?